# Почему при удалении элемента из списка в цикле for, пропускается след. элемент списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

При удалении элемента в цикле `for` с помощью функции `remove` или `pop` почему то пропускается след. элемент списка. 
Пример:

```py
cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for c in cards:
    if c == 3:
        cards.remove(c)
    print(c)

print(cards)
```

Результат:

```py
1
2
3
5
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

В выводе видно что не печатается `4`, интересно почему? а в конечном списке он есть.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471662/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-for-in-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B?rq=1

Comment: Таких вопросов было миллион, как бы найти подходящий дубликат...

Answer (score 1):

Потому что удаление элемента сдвигает все последующие элементы списка.

Для наглядности, заменим ваши `12345` на `ABCDE`.

- Вот был список `ABCDE`.
- Вот у вас идет цикл на 3й итерации вы на элементе `C`, и вы решили его удалить. Массив стал `ABDE`.
- В следующей итерации, вы уже на 4м элементе - смотрим, это элемент `E`. А `D` получается "пропущен", действительно.

---

У вас же еще сложнее - вы храните текущий элемент в переменной `c`. То что вы его удаляете из списка, не удаляет его из переменной. Получается, что вы элемент из списка удалили, но все равно напечатали, а следующий "пропустили".

Comment: окей. а как тогда правильно удалить в цикле?
к примеру, игроку раздали 6 карт, ему ходили и он закрыл, теперь мне нужно удалить карту которую закрывал

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Вы спросили "почему" - вот объяснение )

Comment: @legion088 А `cards.remove(3)` вам чем не подходит, зачем цикл?

Comment: всё равно спасибо) теперь понятно как работает remove или pop

Answer (score 1):

Распространённая ошибка среди новичков. Дело в том, что что когда вы итерируетесь с начала списка, и удаляя элементы по очереди все элементы сдвигаются влево, т.к. всегда индексы должны идти по порядку. Для наглядности простой пример:

```
lst = [i+1 for i in range(10)]  # просто заполняет список
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(f"index: {i}")
    print(lst)
    if lst[i]%2==0:
        lst.pop(i)
```

В коде мы бежимся по списку и удаляем каждый чётный элемент в списке, а для удобства так же выводим индекс элемента который будем проверять(я в ручном режиме для простоты понимания добавил стрелочку указывая на какой элемент сейчас "смотрит" программа).

```
index: 0
 v
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index: 1
    v
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index: 2
       v
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index: 3
          v
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index: 4
             v
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index: 5
                v
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
index: 6
               v
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

В конце при таком раскладе мы выйдем за пределы списка и словим ошибку. Если вам необходимо бороться с такого рода ошибкой попробуйте итерироваться наоборот - с конца списка, тогда все элементы не будут сдвигаться, а значит и ошибки не будет. Однако так же стоит заметить что проблема может возникнуть из-за неправильной постановки задачи, например число `3` можно удалить напрямую не проходя по всему списку.

```
cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for c in cards[::-1]: # реверс списка срезами
    if c == 3:
        cards.remove(c)
    print(c)

print(cards)
```

Вывод программы:

```
5
4
3
2
1
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `В конце при таком раскладе мы выйдем за пределы списка и словим ошибку` - не обязательно кстати. Многие итераторы достаточно умны, чтобы верхнюю границу обновлять в каждой итерации.

Comment: По большей части я писал про данный пример, однако вы меня заинтересовали. Можете привести по возможности парочку примеров, хочу немного потыкать сам :)

Comment: Чтобы далеко не ходить, тот же пример автора вопроса - ошибки не выдает.

Comment: Да, верно, сам обратил на это внимание когда писал ответ, но видимо не придал особого значения, благодарю за новую для меня информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил с помощью копии списка (очень уж надо было удалить в цикле):

```py
cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cards_new = cards.copy()

for c in cards:
   cards = cards_new 
    if c == 3:
        cards_new.remove(c)
    print(c)

1
2
3
4
5
[1, 2, 4, 5]

print(cards)
```

Comment: Более разумные способы - 1) Обходить с конца 2) Обходить с помощью while, где индекс увеличивать, если удаления не было

Comment: а если именно первый элемент нужен?

Comment: Первый никуда не денется, будет обработан, как и все другие

Comment: Это понятно, но если нужно начать работу с первого элемента?

Comment: Я, видимо, не понимаю этого вопроса